# Were 400 people arrested in Russia for social media posts in 2018?

Tags: russia, law-enforcement, social-media

In a 2019 interview John Anderson interviewed Konstantin Kisin ([excerpt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r7GRx8Sl-s), [original video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pvv5kcecnp4)). The discussion is transcribed by the OP of [Were over 3000 persons arrested in Britain for social media posts in 2018?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/54123/were-over-3000-persons-arrested-in-britain-for-social-media-posts-in-2020). I is the interviewer and K is for Konstantin.

> K: In Russia last year 400 people were arrested for things that they
> posted on social media. Obviously this country is very different. How
> many do you think were arrested in Britain for what they said in
> social media?
>
> I: ...
>
> K: Take a guess.
>
> I: I've no idea.
>
> K: 3300 I:
> Really? Arrested for things that they said on social media? ...

The 3300 figure is most likely taken from a [2017 piece in The Times](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/police-arresting-nine-people-a-day-in-fight-against-web-trolls-b8nkpgp2d) (thanks to [this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/54133/35241) answer).

> More than 3,300 people were detained and questioned last year over
> so-called trolling on social media and other online forums, a rise of
> nearly 50 per cent in two years, according to figures obtained by The
> Times.

But the statement is phrased such that the numbers certainly need not be restricted to the offences cited by the times.

**How many people were arrested in Russia in 2018 for social media posts, and what definition of "for" is this figure based on?**

Related question: [Were over 3000 persons arrested in Britain for social media posts in 2018?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/54123/were-over-3000-persons-arrested-in-britain-for-social-media-posts-in-2020)

Comment: With current war going on, it might be tricky to get reliable information regarding -well- virtually anything from Russia at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

If "last year" also means 2017 for this data, it looks to be true (but it's unclear if these were arrests or just cases), according to [Newsweek](https://www.newsweek.com/2018/10/19/how-social-media-post-russia-can-land-you-jail-1157822.html?amp=1):

> The police raid on Markin's home came amid Russia's escalating crackdown on social media activity. Agora, a Russian human rights group, says law enforcement has opened 411 criminal cases against internet users in Russia in 2017, compared with 298 cases in 2016.

The paper [(Con)trolling the Web: Social Media User Arrests, State-Supported Vigilantism and Citizen Counter- Forces in Russia](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/17440572.2020.1719836) gives some details into the laws, and the [Human Rights Center Memorial](https://memohrc.org/ru/monitorings/ne-tolko-pervaya-chast-za-kakie-posty-vas-vse-eshche-smogut-posadit-posle-popravok) (in Russian) gives some examples of arrests.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that 'arrested', 'detained' and 'had criminal cases opened against' mean very different things, but often are used almost interchangeably in media.

Comment: "law enforcement has opened 411 criminal cases against internet users in Russia in 2017" This is a rather weak statement, when you think about it. Is there a more specific one?

Comment: @user76284 More specific how? The last link has info like "Alexander Byvshev… is being persecuted for publishing pro-Ukrainian poems on the Internet" (translated by Google).

Comment: Uhm, yeah, but the question is about the *total* . I never doubted that there were 400 people, I doubted that the number isn't much higher. You didn't explain at all how you arrive at a 400 *total* and why this is the right number and shouldn't include a bunch of other arrests that might have been made based on information gathered from social media posts.